# Display: table overflow parent div in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

**Problem and question**

When using display: table and display: table-cell to vertical align a element, Firefox overflow the parent container width. See live demo to inspect code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hew storeloader" href="/stores/arti-zen-eskilstuna-city">
    <div class="holder hp100" style="height: 325px;">
        <div class="storecontent">
            <img alt="" src="/img/logo-white.svg">
            <p>Arti.Zen Eskilstuna City</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
section.stores .storeloader {
    width: 47.82609%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4.34783%;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

section.stores .storeloader .holder {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
section.stores .storeloader .holder .storecontent {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: it's working fine here on Chrome. Can you show us a preview of firefox?

Comment: and on firefox aswell.

Comment: Solved by `table-layout: fixed;` on the container using `display: table`.

Comment: answer your own question and accept it so that others who may face the same issue might get their issue resolved by seeing this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by `table-layout: fixed;` on the container using `display: table`